# How to store mpz_t from gmlib on a mongo db?

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, gmp, bignum

I'm using GMP library to manage big numbers in a c++ code. I'm also using mongocxx client to connect and make queries to a mongodb database. How can I store a mpz_t number in a mongo database? Or even better, how can I transform mpz_t into a NumeberLong in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, on what you are planning to do. MongoDB does not have an arbitrary precision number type, so you essentially have two options:

If the number type fits in a **64-bit integer**, you can use the functions

```
unsigned long valint = mpz_get_ui(val);
// or
long valint = mpz_get_si(val);
```

to convert the number to a 64-bit integer and store it in a `NumberLong` datatype.

Otherwise, you can always convert the number `val` to a string with

```
char *valstr = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, val);
```

and store it as text in the database. This might be the safest solution, if you only want to *store* the number and do not need to process it at *database level*.